# Gorm not creating entries

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm new to go and I'm a little confused, why the following:

```
acccountTypeModelWallet := accounttypes.AccountType{Type: "wallet", Name: "Wallet"}
if db.First(&acccountTypeModelWallet).RecordNotFound() {
    fmt.Println("Account Type `Wallet` not found. Creating..")
    err := db.Create(&acccountTypeModelWallet).Error
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
}

acccountTypeModelBankAccount := accounttypes.AccountType{Type: "bankaccount", Name: "Bank Account"}
if db.First(&acccountTypeModelBankAccount).RecordNotFound() {
    fmt.Println("Account Type `Bank Account` not found. Creating..")
    err := db.Create(&acccountTypeModelBankAccount).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return false, err
    }
}

acccountTypeModelExchange := accounttypes.AccountType{Type: "exchange", Name: "Exchange Account"}
if db.First(&acccountTypeModelExchange).RecordNotFound() {
    fmt.Println("Account Type `Exchange Account` not found. Creating..")
    err := db.Create(&acccountTypeModelExchange).Error
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
}
```

Only inserts "Wallet" into the database, but not "Bank Account" and "Exchange"? None of the entries exist at the time of execution so all of them should be created.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not checking for errors on `db.First`. What happens if your struct doesn't match your schema?

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors. I also checked with '.GetErrors()' nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after logging out the queries I found the mistake. It was querying all of the entries without any conditions. After adding `.Where()` it worked.

```
if db.Where(&acccountTypeModelExchange).First(&accounttypes.AccountType{}).RecordNotFound()
```